# Every generated user, generates two new JS

Tags: javascript

I cant for the life of me figure how to get this to work...

```js
const nr_invites = 2;
const depth = 8;
let curr_depth = 0;

const user = { 
 id: '',
  invitor: ''
}

function User(iid, invitorId) {
  this.id = iid + 1
  this.invitor = invitorId;
  
  console.log('generating ' + this.id + ' invited by ' + this.invitor)
  curr_depth++
  
if ( curr_depth <= depth ) {
    for ( var z = 0; z < nr_invites; z++ ) {
      let user = new User( this.id, this.invitor )
    }
    this.invitor = this.invitor + 1
  }
}

window.onload = function simulate () { 
 console.log('Starting simulation ...')
 let user = new User( 0, 0 )
}
```

Output SHOULD be so that every one user invites two users
below is expected output:

```
"Starting simulation ..."
"generating 1 invited by 0"
"generating 2 invited by 0"
"generating 3 invited by 1"
"generating 4 invited by 1"
"generating 5 invited by 2"
"generating 6 invited by 2"
"generating 7 invited by 3"
```

and so on..
What i have managed is either increment on every console log, or none at all.

But i just cant figure how to get invitation number to stay...
I have managed about 100 different styles of skipping numbers and other stuff but cant find any way to get it the way it should go..

Comment: *But i just cant figure how to get invitation number to stay...* <-- What does that mean? What, exactly, is the problem? What output are you getting? Is what you showed what you are getting or what you should get?

Comment: Change `for ( z = 0;` to `for ( var z = 0;` and see if things change for you

Comment: Also `this.invitor` is never being incremented.

Comment: You should be careful mutating global variables like `curr_depth`; you probably want it to be a _local_ variable so each recursive iteration has its own version of the variable.

Comment: Where should i increment this.invitor? i keep getting either incriment on every console log or none

Comment: @Taplar added invitor increment, now it adds it on every console log

Comment: @Jacob i know, but thats not the problem and im starting to be desparate..

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental problem with your code that will be hard to get around.  You want to limit by depth but call the next ones in the constructor.  The only way that is going to work is if each one has only one child.  It's easier to separate out the construction from the invitation process.

That's what I try to do here:

```js
class User {
  constructor (iid, invitorId) {
    this .id = iid
    this .invitor = invitorId
    this .invitees = []
    console.log('generating ' + this.id + ' invited by ' + this.invitor)
  }
  
  invite (ids) {
    this .invitees = ids .map (id => new User(id, this.id))
    return this .invitees
  }
}

const extendInvitations = (initialId, total, per) => {
  const user = new User(initialId, null)
  const allUsers = [user]
  const queue = [user]
  while (allUsers .length < total) {
    const user = queue .shift ()
    const newInvites = user .invite (
      [... Array (Math .min (per, total - allUsers.length))] 
        .map ((_, i) => initialId + allUsers .length + i)
    )
    newInvites .forEach (invite => {
      queue.push(invite)
      allUsers.push(invite)
    })
  }
  return allUsers
}

console .log (
  extendInvitations (0, 8, 2) .map (({id, invitor}) => ({id, invitor}))
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`User` is a class with a constructor function and an `invite` method.  That method takes an array of ids and creates new Users with those ids and its own id as the invitor.  It stores these locally as a property of the User, but if that's not important, you could remove the instantiation of `this .invitees` from the constructor and update `invite` to look like this:

```js
  invite (ids) {
    return ids .map (id => new User(id, this.id))
  }
```

The main function here is `extendInvitations`.  That takes a starting id, the total number to generate, and the number of invitations per User.  It maintains two variables in a `while` loop: a list of the users we've created so far and a queue of the ones who have not yet issued invitations.  We loop as long as there are invitations left to offer, giving the next available invitor the chance to invite (up to) `per` invitations, by creating their ids and passing them to that User's `invite` method.

This function returns an array of Users.

If you wanted, you could make the `extendInvitations` function a static member of `User`, just be writing it instead as

```js
User.extendInvitations = (initialId, total, per) => {
  // ...
}
```

(This is very odd code for me nowadays.  I nearly always write functional JS.  Switching to OOP is odd, and I may have done something silly here.)

Comment: Whoa, thank you so much! i try to read this few times and understand and then prop accept this, thanks!